# Gitlab Cannot start runsv is not running

Tags: gitlab, centos7, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I just upgraded my gitlab-ce version to the latest version using this command

```
sudo yum install gitlab-ce-12.1.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64
```

the upgrade works well, but after restart the gitlab service won't start,
when I run this command

```
sudo gitlab-ctl start

fail: alertmanager: runsv not running
fail: gitaly: runsv not running
fail: gitlab-monitor: runsv not running
fail: gitlab-workhorse: runsv not running
fail: grafana: runsv not running
fail: logrotate: runsv not running
fail: nginx: runsv not running
fail: node-exporter: runsv not running
fail: postgres-exporter: runsv not running
fail: postgresql: runsv not running
fail: prometheus: runsv not running
fail: redis: runsv not running
fail: redis-exporter: runsv not running
fail: sidekiq: runsv not running
fail: unicorn: runsv not running
```

and then I try to start the gitlab-runsv by using this command

```
systemctl start gitlab-runsvdir.service
```

But it freezes and not doing anything!!, I must use the CTRL+C to quit
and when I run the journal-ctl it don't showing anything.

```
journalctl -u gitlab-runsvdir.service
-- No entries --
```

My Environment is Centos 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the yum update and restart again after that I did the gitlab-ctl reconfigure, now the gitlab services are working again.

Answer (score 25):

I faced the problem on my ubuntu-20. Previously i had disabled my gitlab-runsvdir.service. That was the reason for my problem. so what i did

```
sudo systemctl enable gitlab-runsvdir.service
sudo systemctl start gitlab-runsvdir.service
```

Answer (score 5):

I left this answer on a similar issue: [Gitlab not starting after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547419/65080102)

I ran into a similar runsv error, but only saw it for once service, not the whole list you have. These steps are a log of my attempts to get it working - probably not a direct line, but my local Gitlab does work now:

In the CentOS vm:

- vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
- - change the external_url from http://example.gitlab.com to http://192.168.1.131
- sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
- - first observed the error runsv not running
- yum update -y
- sudo gitlab-ctl status
- sudo gitlab-ctl restart
- sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
- systemctl start gitlab-runsvdir.service
- systemctl status gitlab-runsvdir.service
- sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
- - still saw an error about runsv not running, several times, but it was never a blocker and the reconfigure was successful

On host

- navigate to 192.168.1.131
- See the prompt for root password

As for the issue with Postgres, I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by leftover `runit` lock files in Gitlab:

```
rm /opt/gitlab/service/*/supervise/lock
gitlab-ctl restart
```