# Install GitLab community edition on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: installation, gitlab, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to install GitLab community edition on ubuntu 20.04
I've followed below commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y curl openssh-server ca-certificates
curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

I don't know what to do in command 5, how to edit the GitLab configuration file to set hostname and other parameters:

```
sudo vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

How to install Gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

Your point 5 (`sudo vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`) is the next logical step.

Change the `external_url` from `http://example.gitlab.com` to the local IP of your Ubuntu server, for instance http://192.168.1.131

In "[Install and Configure Gitlab on Ubuntu](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu.html) ", you will find other settings regarding emails and email settings.
But for now, that is enough to start.

Once you have made your changes:

```sh
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl status
```

If there is any error, check the integrity of your GitLab installation with

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info --trace
```

You can see other troubleshooting steps in "[Gitlab not starting after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59547419/6309)" (which should help even on a more recent Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks for your response, what changes am I suppose to make after executing command--> sudo vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
Please, help me out I'm new to GitLab.

Comment: @user17551439 After changing the rb file, you can start with the two commands I mention in my answer.

Comment: I'm asking what changes do I need to do in the rb file?

Comment: @user17551439 Sorry, I misread. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. One more thing can I use command, sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlabce.example.com"                                                                        instead of  sudo vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb for changing external url to the local IP ?

Comment: @user17551439 I don't think so: it is better to edit it directly in the rb file.